# How to run full text search on help pages offline (from Yelp / gnome-help or something other)?

Tags: search, documentation, offline, helpfile, yelp

I have both Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS installed.

I want to search for documentation and read it off-line (as it is included to the installed packages in `/usr/share/help` and other locations). As far I can understand it has three formats:

- HTML - `.page` (`dpkg -S .page | grep -E /usr/share/help | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc -l` returns 12 results)
- DocBook - `.docbook` (`dpkg -S .docbook | grep -E /usr/share/help | awk '{print $1}' | sort | uniq | wc -l` returns 21 results)
- ManPage (many from `manpath` = `/usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man`)

These files are rendered by Yelp program (from `yelp` package) with executables `yelp` and `gnome-help`.

**Notes:**

1. here on AskUbuntu was [similar question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1011427/66509) about ScrollKeeper database (provided by `rarian-compat` package) without answer;
2. there is a [bug 726439 named "Search for document returns an Unknown error: 'URI xref:search=' could not be parsed" on LauchPad.net (from 2011 year)](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/yelp/+bug/726439) about broken(?) search in Yelp. If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to search `searchterm` in current version of Yelp it still returns

   > **Unknown Error**
   >   The URI ‘xref:search=searchterm’ could not be parsed.

Of course I can run the `grep` over all these files, but is it possible to run such search from Yelp?

Comment: There are also info pages and actual `.html` files in the docs of some packages.

Answer (score 0):

This is especially for man pages in Linux.

```
find -name "cp.1.gz"| xargs zcat
```

Comment: What about `man -k yousearch| ?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
yelp man:<command>
```

For example:

```
yelp man:cp
```

Comment: I need ***search***, not man-page of known application